# problems with obtaining data from an html page to a function for loading data into the database

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to get the values ​​that populate the table and, in case of input, also the values ​​entered manually.

```
@app.route ('/checkResult', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def control Outcomes ():
"" "Function to render the page of the results insertion" ""
    language = request.args.get ("language")
    level = request.args.get ("level")
    session = request.args.get ("session")
    info = request.args.get ("info") or None
    written = request.args.get ("written") or None
    oral = request.args.get ("oral") or None
    if language is None or level is None or session is None:
        sessions = app.model.getSessions ()
        return render_template ('loadingElements.html', login = loginStr (), sessions = sessions, warning = 'Select valid language, level and / or session', category = app.category)
    else:
        resultList= app.model.getResults (language, level, session)
        app.sessionID = session
        return render_template ('editResults.html', login = loginStr (), resultList= resultList, session = app.sessionID, category = app.category)
```

this is the function that initializes the page and it works: it populates the table correctly.
Subsequently, after viewing the table, if a result is not present, a text string appears which allows you to enter a number. However, once I click "register" I can't get all the values ​​in the table row.

```
<table class = "table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class = "right"> # </th>
            <th align = "center"> IdGia </th>
            <th align = "center"> Serial number </th>
            <th align = "center"> Name </th>
            <th align = "center"> Surname </th>
            <th align = "center"> Session Id </th>
            <th align = "center"> Language </th>
            <th align = "center"> Level </th>
            <th align = "center"> Computerized Result </th>
            <th align = "center"> Written Result </th>
            <th align = "center"> Oral Result </th>
            <th align = "center"> Confirm insertion </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>

    {% - for attribute in listEsiti%}
        <tr>
            <td class = "right"> {{ns.num}} {% set ns.num = ns.num + 1%} </td>
            <td align = "center"> {{attribute [0]}} </td>
            {% if attribute [1] == None%}
                <td align = "center"> </td>
            {% else%}
                <td align = "center"> {{attribute [1]}} </td>
            {% endif%}
                <td align = "center"> {{attribute [2]}} </td>
            <td align = "center"> {{attribute [3]}} </td>
            <td align = "center"> {{session}} </td>
            <td align = "center"> {{attribute [4]}} </td>
            <td align = "center"> {{attribute [5]}} </td>
            {% if attribute [6] is none%}
                <td align = "center"> <input type = "int" placeholder = "100" id = "info" name = "info"> </td> <br/> <br/>
            {% else%}
                <td align = "center"> {{attribute [6]}} </td>
            {% endif%}
            {% if attribute [7] is none%}
                <td align = "center"> <input type = "int" placeholder = "100" id = "written" name = "written"> </td> <br/> <br/>
            {% else%}
                <td align = "center"> {{attribute [7]}} </td>
            {% endif%}
            {% if attribute [8] is none%}
                <td align = "center"> <input type = "int" placeholder = "100" id = "oral" name = "oral"> </td> <br/> <br/>
            {% else%}
                <td align = "center"> {{attribute [8]}} </td>
            {% endif%}
            <!-- <td align = "center"> <input class = "btn" type = "submit" value = "Record register"> </td> <br/> <br/> <-->
            <td align = "center"> <a href = "{{url_for ('InsertResult', idGia = attribute [0], language = attribute [4], level = attribute [5], info = attribute [6], written = written, oral = oral, session = session)}} "type =" submit "class =" btn btn-primary "> Register </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The one above is the table that causes me problems while below I report the function that should record the results but that does not work

```
    @ app.route ('/ insertResult', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def insert Results ():
    idGia = request.args.get ('idGia')
    language = request.args.get ("language")
    level = request.args.get ("level")
    info = request.args.get ("info") or None
    written = request.args.get ("written") or None
    oral = request.args.get ("oral") or None
    idPeriodoDid = request.args.get ("session") or None
    studentID = request.args.get (idGia)
    idPeriodoDid = sessionapp  #global
    msg = ''
    
    if not (written is None):
        percentage = written
        msg + = app.model.insertNewResult (language, level, written, written, percentage, studentID, idPeriodoDid, 1)
        
    if not (oral is None):
        percentage = oral
        msg + = app.model.insertNewResult (language, level, oral, oral, percentage, studentID, idPeriodoDid, 2)
        
    if not (info is None):
        percentage = info
        msg = app.model.insertNewResult (language, level, info, info, percentage, studentID, idPeriodoDid, 0)
        
    resultList= app.model.getEsitiInformatizzatoPerInsinsertion (language, level, idPeriodoDid)
    return render_template ('loadingReults2.html', login = loginStr (), resultList= listEsits, category = app.categoria, alert = msg)
```

after entering the results manually and pressing "register" I would expect something similar to

- idGia = 1234
- language = ENGLISH
- level = B2
- info = **70**
- written = **60**
- oral = **90**
- idPeriodoDid = 1
- studentID = 1

while i get

- idGia = 1234
- language = ENGLISH
- level = B2
- info = **None**
- written = **None**
- oral = **None**
- idPeriodoDid = 1
- studentID = 1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the input type attribute value [ int ] is not a thing, instead use number, or date, etc...

Second, u didnt even close your input tags, close them like so

```
<input attributes />
```

These are some important ones and the unclosed tags can interfere with other tags causing attributes to not work as expected

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I fixed the problems you reported to me but I still can't get the data provided in input.
I think there is an error with url_for in the "info", "written", "oral" parameters.for example it seems that "written = written" doesn't work